# Python shell and execfile scope

Tags: python, ipython, execfile

I'm working from inside an ipython shell and often need to reload the script files that contain my functions-under-construction.

Inside my main.py I have:

def myreload():
    execfile("main.py")
    execfile("otherfile.py")

Calling myreload() works fine if I have already ran in the same ipython session the execfile commands directly.

However, for some reason, if the session is fresh and I just called execfile("main.py"), then myreload() doesn't actually make the functions from inside otherfile.py available. It doesn't throw any error though.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functions create a new scope. `execfile()` runs the script in the current scope. What you are doing will not work.

Answer (score 2):

If you seek to learn the actual correct usage of *ipython* (i.e. in interactive mode), then you should use magic commands like:

```
%run
```

and

```
%edit
```

Check help for those functions with `%run?`. This provides explicit examples.

See also http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/interactive/tutorial.html

Comment: Also check how to reload python module http://stackoverflow.com/questions/437589/how-do-i-unload-reload-a-python-module?rq=1